# Multiplying a vector by a constant

Tags: geometry

This is probably a very silly question, but I just can't remember... If $\vec{u}=-8i+32j$, how can I multiply it by a constant $a$? Would the new vector be: $\vec{u}=-8ai+32j$ ?

Comment: That is correct. $a u=-8ai+32aj$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite.

The new vector would be $u=-8ai+32aj$

The constant (called a scalar) is multiplied to both components to ensure that both components (i and j) are 'scaled' by the same factor, thus ensuring that the vector is pointing in the same direction.

Answer (score 1):

$$c(ai+bj)=(ac)i+(bc)j$$ In general, the constant distributes through all the components of the vector. Think of it as "scaling" the vector geometrically, then it should make sense.